# *nix - how can I block programs binding to a port range?

Tags: linux, unix

I want to prevent users from potentially using websockets, there is apache running on port 80. What are the options?

Answer (score 1):

If you are root the you can use ipfilter to block the ports

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/iptables-block-port/